# What is the Recommended Reading Order For Marvel Noir?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order

I am currently trying to get caught up on as many Marvel stories as possible and was trying to figure out the recommended reading order for the Marvel Noir timeline. Here are the issues in question:

- Luke Cage Noir #1-4,
- Daredevil Noir #1-4,
- Punisher Noir #1-4,
- Iron Man Noir #1-4,
- Spider-Man Noir #1-4,
- Spider-Man Noir: Eyes Without a Face #1-4,
- Deadpool Pulp #1-4,
- X-Men Noir #1-4,
- "The Sentinels",
- X-Men Noir: The Mark of Cain #1-4,
- Wolverine Noir #1-4,
- Weapon X Noir # 1 (I believe it's a Marvel One-Shot).

Comment: Is there anything I can do to edit this question to get an answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough on the topic to answer, but you might want to note that Spider-Man Noir also shows up in the Spider-Verse event.

Comment: Is this any help? https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Noir_Reading_Order

Comment: To an extent, yes, but if you're going to include Web Warriors, then you would also need to include Spider-Verse, Spider-Geddon, The Amazing Spider-Man, Peter Porker: The Spectacular Spider-Ham, Spider-Gwen, Spider-Man 2099, etc. Which is why I only requested Noir, to prevent an insanely long list